# Android notifyDataSetChanged for nested Adapter doesn't work

Tags: android

In my `SectionsListAdapter` adapter i have nested `Adapter` named `MonthLessonsList`, after get date from web service and set new data and call `notifyDataSetChanged` method for adapter, main adapter as `SectionsListAdapter` can be refresh, but nested adapter dont refresh and after calling `notifyDataSetChanged` for that, doesn't work correctly and don't show new data

call and set new data from `Fragment`:

```
monthSectionsItems = SQLite.select().from(MonthSections.class).queryList();
adapter.setData(monthSectionsItems);
```

and my Adapter with nested adapter:

```
public class SectionsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SectionsListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private final OnItemSelected listener;
    private List<MonthSections> list;
    private Context context;
    private MonthLessonsList lessonsListAdapter;

    public SectionsListAdapter(List<MonthSections> followingsList, Context mContext, OnItemSelected listener) {
        this.list = followingsList;
        this.context = mContext;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.sections_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.indicatorIcon.setText(list.get(position).getSection_month_name());
        ...

        List<SectionLesson> lessonsList = list.get(position).getLessons();
        lessonsListAdapter = new MonthLessonsList(lessonsList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        holder.userChildCategories.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        holder.userChildCategories.setAdapter(lessonsListAdapter);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void setData(List<MonthSections> data) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        lessonsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<MonthSections> getData() {
        return list;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

            section_title.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }

    public class MonthLessonsList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MonthLessonsList.LessonsViewHolder> {
        private List<SectionLesson> lessonItem;

        public class LessonsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView title;

            public LessonsViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            }
        }

        public MonthLessonsList(List<SectionLesson> lists) {
            this.lessonItem = lists;
        }

        @Override
        public LessonsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.child_list_row, parent, false);

            return new LessonsViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LessonsViewHolder holder, int position) {
            SectionLesson lesson = lessonItem.get(position);
            holder.title.setText("درس: " + (position + 1) + ") " + lesson.getTitle());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return lessonItem.size();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try `notifyDataSetChanged()`line at last of method `setData`?

Comment: @Khemraj yes, it donesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Declare child adapter inside `onBindViewHolder`, and remove from global level.
And no need to notify child adapter. Because that will be automatically filled when parent `onBindViewHolder` is called.
Like

```
MonthLessonsList lessonsListAdapter = new MonthLessonsList(lessonsList);
holder.userChildCategories.setAdapter(lessonsListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two adapter AdapterA and AdapterB, now AdapterB is setting inside of AdapterA and you need to update data in AdapterB just create a method inside AdapterA like this:

```
fun setList(adapterAList:ArrayList<Object>,adapterBlist:ArrayList<Object>) {
      adapterAList.clear()
      adapterAList.addAll(daysList)
      adapterBlist.clear()
      adapterBlist.addAll(dayOfWeekList)
      notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

now call this method from your Activity/Fragment and give both list for AdapterA and AdapterB and this will change your data inside a Nested RecyclerView.